# Selecting all values greater than a number in a panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this with more than 50 columns(for years from 1963 to 2016). I was looking to select all countries with a population over a certain number(say 60 million). Now, when I looked, all the questions were about picking values from a single column. Which is not the case here. I also tried
`df[df.T[(df.T > 0.33)].any()]` as was suggested in an answer. Doesn't work. Any ideas?

The data frame looks like this:

```
Country Country_Code   Year_1979  Year_1999   Year_2013
  Aruba          ABW     59980.0      89005    103187.0
 Angola          AGO   8641521.0   15949766  25998340.0
Albania          ALB   2617832.0    3108778   2895092.0
Andorra          AND     34818.0      64370     80788.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First filter only columns with `Year` in columns names by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), compare all rows and then test by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) at least one matched value per row:

```
df1 = df[(df.filter(like='Year') > 2000000).any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
   Country Country_Code  Year_1979  Year_1999   Year_2013
1   Angola          AGO  8641521.0   15949766  25998340.0
2  Albania          ALB  2617832.0    3108778   2895092.0
```

Or compare all columns without first 2 selected by positons with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = df[(df.iloc[:, 2:] > 2000000).any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
   Country Country_Code  Year_1979  Year_1999   Year_2013
1   Angola          AGO  8641521.0   15949766  25998340.0
2  Albania          ALB  2617832.0    3108778   2895092.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect. What does (like='Year') do? and the ";" after 2 in the iloc one..does it mean it will select all the columns after the second-1 ?

Comment: @RakeshGulati - `filter` check columns names and if find `Year` it return all columns contains `Year`. `iloc` function select all columns with omiting first 2, here `Country` and `Country_Code`